# Which windows services are ok to: SC Type= own?

Tags: windows, encryption, bitlocker, windows-services, efs

Looking at the best answer to ["How to find memory usage of individual Windows services"](https://serverfault.com/questions/12278/how-to-find-memory-usage-of-individual-windows-services) posted on Server Fault it looks like `SC Config ServiceName Type= own` is the best way to 'split-off' services under their own process in order to view what resources they're using; however one comment to this answer by @Beau cautions to be extremely careful you don't split off services related to the EFS(Encrypted File System) service.

So my related questions are: I'd assume splitting services not under an EFS process would be fine, but which services really are ok to split-off on their own, would just moving EFS out to its own be the only issue, how about moving any of the others associated with EFS out to their own and leaving EFS as is? More specific to my situation where I have wuauserv(Windows Update), BITS(Background Intelligent Transfer Service), and BDESVC(BitLocker Drive Encryption Service) all grouped under one process not with EFS; am I ok splitting any of these out on their own?

These seem like the kind of questions where if you just try it and see what happens, then you'll be left with a nice chance to learn how to install Windows. I've tried Googling around but either I'm doing it wrong, or there doesn't seem like there is any info out there which really addresses these situations. So any advice especially from someone who's learned the hard way would be greatly appreciated.

Thnx in adv.

Comment: I always split WU service on it's own. Also look in eventlog for other service crashes and here you can configure to the crashing service on it's own so that the service doesn't kill other services in case of a crash

Comment: @magicandre1981, maybe I've failed to make my point properly. It's not that a service is crashing, I'd just like to see what memory and resources the service is consuming. My fear is that after I split off services that are grouped under the same process as encryption ones then those services will no longer see decrypted data, and if that data happens to be the windows system folder I may end up in a bad way.

Comment: make a complete backup before doing such changes.

Comment: @magicandre1981, good advice, but I'd imagine that restoring from a backup is that much more difficult when the drive wouldn't boot and is encrypted...

Comment: granted i can't see how splitting off WU would stop it from booting. I'm just looking for someone with exp regarding the BitLocker to weigh in.

Comment: clone windows to a 2nd identical drive, so you can swap the drives if splitting makes Windows unbootable.